# change the default category page layout in mediawiki

Tags: templates, hook, mediawiki

I was thinking if there was a way to change the Category page's default layout? I was thinking of including featured articles and their thumbnails just below the category text. I know that I can do this by editing the category page by hand but I would really want to make it so that all categories will do this by default. Is there a Category Template somewhere? Or is there a certain parameter that I should watch for when hooking to one of the output functions?

[image: This is the proposed layout]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, there is nothing like that in existence AFAIK.  However, with [Extension:NiceCategoryList2](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aNiceCategoryList2), you could probable create a template that generates an output that is fairly close to what you want. You would still have to manually have to place the call to the template on all C: pages though or use a bot to pre-pend it to the top of all the C:s listed on `Special:WantedCategories`.